# Using setProgress on SeekBar within a Fragment doesn't change seekBar position

Tags: android, android-fragments, seekbar, android-seekbar

I have an app with action bar. It has a "Main" fragment and a "Preferences" fragment.

```
@Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

                Fragment fragment = new Main();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                switch(position) {
                    case 0:
                        fragment = new Main();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        fragment = new Preferences();
                        break;
                }
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment1, fragment)
                    .commit();
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                }
            });
```

The "Preferences" fragment has a seekBar that is updated with a value from SharedPreferences. This is the relevant code that makes this within the "Preferences" fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    container.removeAllViews();

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.preferences, container, false);

    fontSizeBar = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.fontSizeBar);
    fontSizeBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Preferences.this.getActivity().getBaseContext());
    final int fontSize = preferences.getInt("fontSize", 10);

    fontSizeBar.setMax(0);
    fontSizeBar.setMax(10);
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            fontSizeBar.setProgress(fontSize);
        }
    });
```

The thing is that the variable "fontSize" comes with a value of 10 and the seekBar is responding to the following event:

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    fontSizeBar.setProgress(progress);
    Log.v("Progress changed", "Font size: " + progress);

}
```

But the seekBar position does not change. I have been searching a lot in SO and Google, no luck until now.

Additional info: I'm using android.support.v4

**UPDATE:**

The following events are not called when I move the seekBar slider. Also, when I change the seekBar slider and then select the main fragment and go back to the preferences fragment, the seekBar is still in the value I selected.

```
@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.v("Start touching", "Font size: " + seekBar.getProgress());
}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.v("Stop touching", "Font size: " + seekBar.getProgress());

}
```

Comment: you're using `setMax` twice on `fontSizeBar`.

Comment: @AbdallahAlaraby removed fontSizeBar.setMax(0); still fontSizeBar not updating.

Comment: does the Log print the "Progress changed" line?

Comment: @AbdallahAlaraby Yes!

Comment: In the `onItemClick` listener, you shouldn't create a new instance of `Main` and `Preferences` every time the user clicks one of them. You might be loading a fragment but it is not visible on the phone UI. hide and show the previously created instances instead (if exist).

Comment: @AbdallahAlaraby Changed that code to this:

Comment: Fragment fragment = null;
          Fragment main = new Main();
          Fragment preferences = new Preferences();
             FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
             switch(position) {
                 case 0:
                     fragment = main;
                     break;
                 case 1:
                     fragment = preferences;
                     break;
             }
             fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                 .replace(R.id.fragment1, fragment)
                 .commit();

Comment: @AbdallahAlaraby Still not updating the seekBar.

Comment: Why are you calling `fontSizeBar.setProgress(progress);` inside the `onProgressChanged` listener? Isn't this recursive like that?

Comment: @AbdallahAlaraby Sorry for that. It was a line added in the debugging process.